no hyperref in index of html
Here an mwe off this site. If i process it with pdflatex i get the hyperrefs. But if i process it with htlatex the index does not have working hyperrefs. What am i missing?
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up. 

\printindex

\end{document}


TeX4ht needs a build file with an explicit command for index generation. Save the following code as build.lua:
Make:htlatex{}
Make:makeindex{}
Make:htlatex{}

First Make:htlatex runs LaTeX. This is necessary to save the index entries. Make:makeindex creates the index using Makeindex. You can also select other  index processors using Make:xindex or Make:xindy. Last Make:htlatex will create HTML with the created index.
You can compile your document using:
$ make4ht -e build.lua filename.tex

You may need to compile the document two times to get correct links.
This is the result:

